# Advance Search - Display as Mailings - No options appear for export

Tags: advanced-search

I am trying to get data to see what email donors clicked on. I do an advanced search, display results as mailing, but the options to export are missing. I attached my options in an image, but it appears to do the same no matter what search options are chosen.

D7, Civi 5.42, Shoreditch and Greenwitch

[image]

Comment: Does this problem occur if you disable Shoreditch?

Comment: Yes it does with greenwhich too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not find the clicked email using advance search - But, work around would be:

**STEP 1:** Add all the contact to a group/smart group (if you create a smart group - you don't have to run the same advance search again and again)

**STEP 2:** Go to Menu - Reports ->Mailing Reports ->Mail Clickthroughs

**STEP 3:** In the filter select the group which you have created

Finally run the report and now you should see all the email and click through URL too which can now be exported

I guess this helps !!!